# I am taking a very large Fortran binary file, and rewriting it into a *.csv file, and I am getting a MemoryError -- what are my options?

Tags: python, csv, memory

So, I will be honest. I am a grad student, and I don't really write pretty code. That might be half the problem.

My Python program is extremely simple: I read records from a Fortran binary file, unpack them using `struct.unpack`, and then convert the `tuple` returned by `struct.unpack` into a `list`.

I then write this `list` of records into a *.csv file using Python's `csv` module.

I use Python 2.7.

Why this route of workflow? Well, the Fortran binary files come from an annoyingly closed-source program that hasn't been updated for a while. All the authors have done is release a document outlining the structure of each Fortran binary file, so I can use something like `struct.unpack` to read data from them.

Not everyone in the lab can program, but everyone can use Excel. So it would be nice if we could convert these dirty binary files into more rationally organized *.csv files that anyone can open up.

We plan on automating further post-processing in order to cut out Excel eventually, and even then, we figure that having our data in conveniently organized *.csv files will still be pretty nice as we can use the `csv` modules reader functions to read data in a way that reflects its organization in the *.csv file.

My computer does have 16 GB of RAM and a 64 bit OS, but I am using 32 bit Python, I am pretty sure. NumPy and SciPy have issues with 64 bit Python, if I am not mistaken.

An immediate, albeit ugly, workarounds come to mind break up the CSV files: i.e. write the information from a Fortran binary file that contains data for 10 time steps into 10 *.csv files, one for each time step. Except, sometimes, there aren't just 10 time steps, but 2000...

Also, each time, I would have to close the file object, and re-open it, figuring out where I last read form...blah blah, it seems to get very messy, very fast.

What other options might I have?

---

Here's some skeleton code that reflects what I am doing in my code:

```
recordSize = 24 #24 bytes in a record

fileObject = open("filepath", "rb")

csvRows = []
while True:
  fout = fileObject.read(recordSize)
  if len(fout) != recordSize:
     break
  else:
    csvRows.append([x for x in struct.unpack("ffffff", fout)])

csvFileObject.writerows(csvRows)
```

I am getting the memory error on the `csvRows.append([x for x in struct.unpack("ffffff", fout)])` line.

Comment: Are you reading the entire file in one gulp? Without seeing even a skeleton of the code, it's difficult to guess how to make things better...

Comment: If you can read the records individually, you shouldn't ever need to store more than one in memory at the same time: unpack one from the file, write it to the csv, repeat until complete.  If you show the code, we can probably suggest the appropriate changes.

Comment: @bgporter I updated to include some skeleton code!

Comment: @DSM As per bgporter's suggestion, and yours, I have included some skeleton code that outlines the method I am using.

Answer (score 3):

well, first of all, you do not give code for us to help you with. I don't mean the 5000 lines hell you've written, but a shorter concise version we can start upon.

> *What other options might I have?*

if you're reaching the memory limit of your python process, it's very likely that you're taking your whole binary file into the memory. Know that you're not filling your 16GB of ram, but only what your system enables you to take for a single process. But you should not need to increase the memory limit for your process, you should improve your algorithm.

So instead of reading everything, converting that gigantic file and writing it done, why don't you just make it a stream? Basically the idea would be:

create a CSV writer:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'w'):
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

read the fortran file one line at a time (usually lines have the same length or have a marker between each statement)

```
    with open('fortran.bin', 'b') as f:
        for data in read_that_line(f):
```

parse and process that line of data

```
            data1, data2, data3, data4 = get_useful_info_from(data)
```

write it to CSV:

```
            writer.write_row([data1, data2, data3, data4])
```

The real deal is in `read_that_line(f)` that needs to return only the relevant data from the file. I can't help you to write this if I don't have the format, but it's either getting data of a given length:

```
def read_that_line(f):
    s = f.read(50)
    while s != "":
        yield s
        s = f.read(50)
```

or it's getting data up until a given delimiter, then change `open()` to `open('fortran.bin', 'b', newline=0x20)`
and iterate over the file using:

```
def read_that_line(f):
    for l in f:
        yield l
```

or it maybe a bit more complicated, and you'll have to reach one byte at a time and return assembler statements once they've been built:

```
def read_that_line(f):
    buf = b""
    while its_not_a_statement_yet(buf):
        buf += f.read(1)
    yield buf
```

then all you'll have in memory is just the size of the line and the temporary variables for each line of fortran data. Even an Arduino-sized machine could handle that!

Here's the problem within your code:

```
# you create a list
csvRows = []
while iterate over the file:
    […]
    ### at each iteration over the file, you append 24 bytes in memory
    csvRows.append([ 24 bytes of data ]) 

### until you get the full size of the fortran binary in your memory, which fills your allowed memory space
### before you're even reaching this line!
csvFileObject.writerows(csvRows)
```

ok, here's an update of your code, taking my advices into account:

```
recordSize = 24 #24 bytes in a record

import csv
### here we open the target csv file that will receive the data
with open('file.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    ### you may want to configure the csv writer to match your csv file preferences
    ### we create a writer object that will take a list as input, and write it down in the csv file
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    ### then we open the fortran binary file
    with open("fortran.bin", "rb") as f:
        ### we initialize the first record in the data variable 
        data = f.read(recordSize)
        ### while we have a full record
        while len(data) != recordSize:
            ### we unpack and write it down to the disk
            writer.write_row([x for x in struct.unpack("ffffff", data)])
            ### and we read the next record, which replace the last one in memory and discarding it
            data = fileObject.read(recordSize)
```

HTH

Comment: I have now included some skeleton code to improve the question. Have a look! A question regarding the method that you suggest: while I am reading little bits from a file, or writing little bits to a file, the "unread"/"already written" bits are not stored in RAM?

Comment: Indeed, they are not stored in RAM anymore. Once an instance of data is not held by a variable, or a list, python discards it and it's not usable anymore. The system then takes care of freeing the memory at the right time. Then that data lives on, only if you wrote it on your disk.

Answer (score 3):

If you simply write them as you go instead of building a giant list of them, you should be okay:

```
import csv, struct

recordSize = 24 #24 bytes in a record

with open("fortran.bin", "rb") as fileObject, open("out.csv", "wb") as fp_out:
    writer = csv.writer(fp_out)
    while True:
        fout = fileObject.read(recordSize)
        if len(fout) != recordSize:
            break
        else:
            writer.writerow(struct.unpack("ffffff", fout))
```

which gives me

```
0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0
0.0,2.0,4.0,6.0,8.0,10.0
0.0,3.0,6.0,9.0,12.0,15.0
0.0,4.0,8.0,12.0,16.0,20.0
```

on some test data I made up, although you might want to write a header at the start; columns deserve names.

A few notes: (1) `[x for x in something_or_other]` is simply `list(something_or_other)`, but here `struct.unpack` returns a `tuple` already which works equally well.  (2) In Python we tend to write `record_size`, not `recordSize`.

---

If you're feeling up to learn a bit more, note that one common pattern in Python to make something lazy is to `yield` elements one-by-one, something like:

```
def read_fortran(filename):
    record_size = 24
    record_format = "f"*6
    with open(filename, "rb") as fp:
        while True:
            row = fp.read(record_size)
            if len(row) < record_size:
                break
            unpacked = struct.unpack(record_format, row)
            yield unpacked
```

`yield` is like a `return`, but it doesn't end the function (the "generator"), it preserves the state until something calls `next` on it at which point it continues.  (`for` loops do this implicitly.)  This allows you to abstract away the iteration logic.  After doing this, you could do something like

```
>>> read_fortran("fortran.bin")
<generator object read_fortran at 0xb0b02144>
>>> rows = read_fortran("fortran.bin")
>>> for row in rows:
...     print(row)
...     
(0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)
(0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0)
(0.0, 3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0, 15.0)
(0.0, 4.0, 8.0, 12.0, 16.0, 20.0)
```

where instead of `print` you could call `writerow` instead, and you're not storing all the rows.

Comment: Oh, this might be a very interesting solution! Using a generator instead! Thanks!